# Deployment of Community with reports issue

Tags: community, reporting, deployment

I have a customer community with the standard community page, where I have component `Report Chart` which references specific report.
I'm deploying Community using Metadata API. I have included `siteDotCom`, `Network`, and `Reports` metadata.

When I deploy the community, the component `Report Chart` on page and report are deployed properly, but the component doesn't reference the report correctly. In `Report Name` of the `Report Chart` component settings, it says None Found. Any suggestions on how to deploy this properly?

[image: Report Chart settings]

Comment: What do you mean by "community with the page"?  Please edit your original post to clarify.

Comment: @DavidCheng hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: @mascot - have you tried deploying the report and report folders first then deploying the Community after. The other thing is does the deployment include the profiles so that the report folder access is included.

Comment: @DaveHumm Yes, I did try the deployment order. And yes, profiles are included. After deployment, I can change the Report Name to the correct one easily. Problem is it is not there right away.

Comment: Have you tried deploying [ReportChartComponentLayoutItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.216.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_layouts.htm) along with? Seems it contains the settings/report name that's configured on the Report Chart component.

Comment: @JayantDas, I'm confused. Isn't ReportChartComponentLayoutItem just part of the Layout metadata? Then it wouldn't work since on community I don't have any page layout used.

Comment: The documentation mentions: *Represents the **settings** for a report chart on a standard or custom page.* You may like to test it out once.